# save file to desktop

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I want user to see save window so that he can save where ever he want same as downloading the attachments from mail.
spring controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/getFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

             ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
             //logic to get the data from database

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**First Answer**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(
    @PathVariable("file_name") String fileName, 
    HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
      // get your file as InputStream
      InputStream is = ...;
      // copy it to response's OutputStream
      IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
      response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      log.info("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '" + fileName + "'");
      throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }

}
```

**Second Option**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{fileName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<byte[]> createPdf(
                 @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {

    byte[] documentBody = this.pdfFramework.createPdf(filename);

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "pdf"));
    header.set("Content-Disposition",
                   "attachment; filename=" + fileName.replace(" ", "_"));
    header.setContentLength(documentBody.length);

    return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(documentBody, header);
}
```

**Third Option**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName) {
    return new FileSystemResource(myService.getFileFor(fileName)); 
}
```

Comment: Can i use any one of the option from above ? but not sure as i want user to save where ever he wants to save in local drive.@ankur-singhal

Comment: @participantjava Pls try the above approach, this will come as a downloadable window wherein user can save wherever he wants to.

Comment: ok.Do you want me to try the 3rd option?But i don't have any specific file to save.As shown in above post, i will get the byte[] data, file name, file extension from database from which i need to construct a file by writing byte[] data in that file and giving the filename etc..@ankur-singhal

Comment: i don't have "{file_name}" , i need to create a file and give the filename with the extension which i will get from database as shown in above post of spring controller /getFile. @ankur-singhal.

Comment: @participantjava Forget about the filename, you should have Byte Array or input stream , just use that. Do not forget to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: sure , i'm trying. If it works i will accept the answer,thanks.